# How to Count a Type of Character that Appears in a String Using a Function in C++?

Tags: c++, string, function, char

The goal of my assignment is to write a C++ program that takes in two variables, a character value and a string value. The program is then, with the use of a user-defined function called **int CountCharacters()** the program is supposed to count the number of times that the user inputted character value is in the user inputted string value.

So far I have been able to code what I think at least is a good foundation, but when I run it, I get a crazy big number that also changes each time I run the program.

Below is the program that I have written so far:

Tested Input: **n Monday**

Expected Output: **1**

Received Output: **22091**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int CountCharacters(char userChar, string userString)  {
   
   int casesFound = 0;
   int n = userString.length();
   
   for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)  {
      if (userString[i] == userChar)  {
         casesFound = casesFound + 1;
      }
   }
   
   return casesFound;
}

int main() {
   
   char cVal;
   string sVal;
   int casesFound;
   
   cin >> cVal;
   getline(cin, sVal);
   
   CountCharacters(cVal, sVal);
   
   cout << casesFound << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `casesFound = CountCharacters(cVal, sVal);` in `main()`.

Comment: Also, strings begin at index 0, but your loop is starting the search at index 1.  And FYI, the standard C++ library has a [`std::count()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) algorithm that you should use instead of rolling your own manual function: `casesFound = std::count(sVal.begin(), sVal.end(), cVal);`

Comment: No compiler warning?  Crank up your command line flags!

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Sorry, my bad, I forget to close the question. I will do that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you got different numbers is that you output `casesFound` without assigning a value to it. Reading uninitialized variables makes your program have [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) - so *anything* could happen. If your function returned `1` it wouldn't have mattered because you do not assign that value to `casesFound`. You can assign the value of your function returned to `casesfound` like this:

```
casesFound = CountCharacters(cVal,sVal);
```

And then proceed to

```
cout<<casesFound;
```

Or you could print the returned value directly without assigning it to a variable:

```
std::cout << CountCharacters(cVal, sVal) << '\n';
```

Also note that you have  bug in your loop. The first index in arrays and strings etc. is `0` in C++, not `1`, so you wouldn't be able to count the `M` in `Monday`.